# Error: Could not find or load main class ExcelReadWrite

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, classpath

I have a class ExcelReadWrite that runs fine when I run it through eclipse.But when I try to run it from command line I need to set classpath of dependent classes.

```
set CLASSPATH=C:\Users\NICSI\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.11\poi-ooxml-3.11.jar;C:\Users\NICSI\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.11\poi-3.11.jar;
```

After setting class path it compiles successfully but when I execute my class then this exception occurs.

> Error: Could not find or load main class ExcelReadWrite

```
 public class ExcelReadWrite {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputFile=args[0];
    String outputFile=args[1];
    System.out.println("inputFile 0   "+inputFile);
    System.out.println("outputFile 0   "+outputFile);
    transformExcelFile(inputFile,outputFile);
    //transformExcelFile("E:\\excel\\inputFile.xlsx","E:\\excel\\outputFile.xlsx");
    }
    }
```

I use following command to compile and execute my class

```
E:\excelTest>javac ExcelReadWrite.java

E:\excelTest>java ExcelReadWrite
Error: Could not find or load main class ExcelReadWrite
```

Comment: How do you run it from command line. Show the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the actual Directory to your classpath:

```
E:\excelTest>java -cp .;%CLASSPATH% ExcelReadWrite
```

Comment: It is inside folder excelTest.My class has no package declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117867/discussion-between-keshav-and-jens).